# How to make Fresh Asian Noodle?

Tags: egg-noodles

How do I make Fresh Asian Noodle (similar to Egg Noodle)? What are the ingredients and the steps to make them? I am asking about noodles, not a dish.

Comment: Welcome! We aren't really a recipe sharing site here, so you'll be better served doing a web search for homemade Asian noodles... this will be aided if you know the name of the specific type of noodle you want to make (there are many different types).

Comment: What do you mean asian noodles? There are so many types, you can at least be more specific

Comment: I think it might be okay asking for basic techniques like this if we knew the noodle (they're probably pretty much a ratio and a method of turning dough into noodles, not the problematic sort of recipe request) but unfortunately there's just no way to tell what kind of noodles you're talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You just make fresh pasta....dry pasta doesn't usually have egg, fresh pasta does....egg noodle is just dried pasta that was made with egg.

Follow a basic fresh pasta recipe using 2 eggs per cup of AP Flour.

You'll want a pasta roller and cutter...You don't **have** to have one, but you really do want one to make life much easier.